# Facing problem in creating Profile in Careers 2.0 of Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, support, jobs

I found that  Stack Overflow profiles are **invitation-only**. see the [link](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/get-one). I tried to invite my gmail id but i am getting **An invitation request has already been made for this email address**. (I have attached screenshot of this.) But I didn't get any invitation in gmail.

How to create Profile in Careers 2.0. I am a regular user of stack overflow you can get my account in the below link:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/111988/sunil-kumar-sahoo

[image]

Comment: Did you request an invite? Why not?

Comment: How to request invite? I have mentioned everything whatever i did.

Comment: I've heard people claim that there is an auto invite system for active SO users. But I don't know if such a system actually exists or works.

Comment: Then it was already requested. Getting an invite is not automatic, you know. They actually look at the details you posted to decide if they want to give one out.

Comment: What I need to do now?

Comment: @CodeInChaos: Yes, there is an automatically invite if you reach a certain threshold in a (certain?) tag. Don't ask me about details...

Answer (score 1):

Requested invites go into a queue, invites do not go out immediately.  This message means you already have a request in queue.

We process this queue manually, so it might take a few days for your request to be processed.

Comment: Perhaps make the error message a bit clearer, so it's obvious that the invite hasn't been sent out yet, and that they need to wait until it's manually reviewed.

Comment: I have made request more than one month before to the same email id. But didn't get still now Again I made request today

Comment: And as we are on the topic of invites, does the auto-invite system actually exist/work?

Comment: Does asking for an invite automatically mean an invite? Do you send out reject emails as well?

Comment: @CodeInChaos yes there is an automatic system for invites that is based on your activity on SO, however how it works is magic and I am not allowed to pull the curtain back.

Comment: @Oded we do reject candidates from the queue silently.  The invite system goes through regular revisions, but I can tell you a few things for certain, particularly about the invite request.  MOST of the invites tell us to look at the persons linked in, blog, github and/or stack overflow accounts, but do not link to them.  That is guaranteed to get you rejected.  Linking to an open source account which just has a bunch of cloned repos and no personal commits is also not going to get you in.