# Does a Stack Overflow profile help improve a resumé? 

Tags: discussion

I am creating a resumé. I want to know whether mentioning stackoverflow profile counts for much in terms of interview factors, e.g. showing my knowledgeability and performance.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/20407/will-high-reputation-in-stack-overflow-help-to-get-a-good-job

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58947/at-what-point-do-you-put-your-so-reputation-in-your-resume

Comment: Make sure not to submit any posts during office hours :)

Comment: Maybe.  Maybe not.

Answer (score 10):

It entirely depends on the person who is going to interview you, I guess. And of course, what your profile looks like. In general, Stack Overflow has become a very well-known resource over the past years - especially in the US, there is a good chance your interviewer knows the site.

If you are referring to your [current Stack Overflow profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1053416/yellow-page), I'd say it won't impress a recruiter much in it current state - it contains 4 questions, one of them downvoted, and only one answer that, while probably helpful, doesn't help prove that you are a knowledgeable person.

Comment: I think _my_ profile scares people off me these days...

Comment: @Oded yeah, I've had the same thought - for one, my "recent comments" are often 2 pages of "what exactly goes wrong? Please be more specific" which make me look like a pedantic asshole. Ah well. :)

Answer (score 2):

Currently the answer is No, as Pekka [already said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120941/152859).

However, if and when you will gain enough reputation you will be invited to create a professional profile [here](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/). ( Stack Overflow Careers site)

This can be introduced in job interviews and will even help you find jobs, pretty similar to LinkedIn.

Comment: I don't think it's down to 'enough reputation'. The invitation algorithm is _top-secret-if-we-told-you-we'd-have-to-kill-you_ kind of stuff - based on previous comments from staff.

Comment: @Mr.D - I got such email at some point: "We’re impressed by your “javascript” tag answers on Stack Overflow. In recognition of your generous spirit, we’d like to invite you to create a professional profile on Stack Overflow Careers 2.0." so it means when you reach enough votes in specific tag - I'm sure there are other "triggers" as well to get invited though. Can't see why it should be so secret - it's simple reward system for good contributors.

Comment: But rep is one of the criteria, that much we know.

Comment: _'yes there is an automatic system for invites that is based on your activity on SO, however how it works is magic and I am not allowed to pull the curtain back'_ - [linky](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/119475/157071)